# Difference between rosrun and directly launching an executable

Tags: rospy, roscpp, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are the differences between :

```
rosrun mynode program
```

And :

```
cd /path/to/mynode
./program
```

Why is the first (I assume) preferred, and when is it required ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58262/difference-between-rosrun-and-directly-launching-an-executable/) by [victorp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4163/victorp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In principle it should do the same.

The difference is that you don't need to know the actual path to `program` in the package.

Also rosrun will run the node of package `mynode`, not the node in `/path/to/mynode`. Usually that is the same, but if you switched you workspace or something like that you might run something of another setup than you think you are.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2